# Find information about a file in a git commit where it has been moved

Tags: git

I try to get the number of line of some files at a given date. To do that, I use a `bash` script, where I do something similar* than:

```
empty_commit="$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)"
old_commit="$(git log -1 --before="$some_date" \
                         --format=format:%h -- "$some_file")"
nb_lines="$(git diff --follow --numstat \
                     "$empty_commit" "$old_commit" -- "$some_file" \
            | cut -f1)"
```

*(I dropped the error management here, for clarity).

It is working pretty well except when the file has been moved precisely in `$old_commit`, i.e. when I have:

```
$ git show "$old_commit" --name-status
...
R100 some_file old_file_name
...
```

In that case, the `git diff` command shown above has an empty output.

To make it work, I need to first detect the situation, and then either:

- do the `git diff` with the commit before `$old_commit` (i.e `"$old_commit"^`). It is working using `$some_file` (the new name) thanks to the `--follow` option,
- **OR** do the `git diff` with `$old_commit` and the old filename

Both solutions work, but it is quite annoying, so I wonder if there is a solution that would always work without having to detect special cases.